# descendingIterator() and descendingSet() test of NavigableSet Interface

Tags: java, collections

I was reading [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/navigableset.html) documentation on Java Collections and decided to test the two methods of NavigableSet Interface as follows. As the doc says for `descendingSet()` that *The returned "view" is backed by the original NavigableSet, so changes to the descending set are also reflected in the original set.* . Upon testing both the methods, I didn't see any changes in original set using descendingSet() method. Please explain why?

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NavigableSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class NavigableSetLearning {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NavigableSet<String> original = new TreeSet<String>();
        original.add("1");
        original.add("2");
        original.add("3");
        original.add("4");
        //Usage of Descending Set Method
        NavigableSet reverse = original.descendingSet();
        System.out.println(original);
        System.out.println(reverse);
        System.out.println(original);

        // Usage of Descending Iterator Method

        /*Iterator it = original.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.print("Original"+it.next()+"\n");

        }

        Iterator reverse = original.descendingIterator();
        //System.out.println(original);
        while(reverse.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("Reversed"+reverse.next()+",");
        }

        Iterator itAgain = original.iterator();

        while(itAgain.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("Original Again"+itAgain.next()+",");

        }
        */


    }

}
```

The output I am getting is as follows:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4] // Was expecting change here as per the doc
```

Comment: ...you *aren't changing `reverse`*. What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that if you remove or add elements to the reversed set derived from `original`, modifications to the set content will be reflected in the first set; it's an alternate view of the same set.

The ordering specified for each set will not be violated as elements are removed or added, or when `descendingSet()` is called.

Comment: I was thinking that after running reverse, if I run the original set, I should be getting the reverse elements as the original ordering gets disturbed.

Comment: No. That would break the contract of a `TreeSet`, which presents elements in the order specified at construction time.

Comment: I see. I tried to add `5` as `reverse.add("5")` and the ordering was preserved like `5,4,3,2,1`.

Comment: And we can't do anything like we did above with descendentIterator() method, right?